# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

I want to if there are no authors/users found exit given the message below. But keep striking   Trying to get property of non-object on the $author_found_count. Why is this? Thanks

```
$find_author = "SELECT user FROM reviews WHERE review_id=$review_id;";

$search_author = mysqli_query($con,$find_author);

$found_author = mysqli_fetch_array($search_author);

$author_found_count = $found_author->num_rows;

//Check to see if any reviews have been found.
if($author_found_count == 0) {

//No reviews found.
exit ("You are not the author of the review. You are not authorised to delete it.");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the num_rows of the php array, but for this purpose you should use mysqli_result object:

```
$author_found_count = $search_author->num_rows;
```

You can also use php function to check if the result set is empty:

```
$author_found_count = count($found_author);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because `num_rows` is not a property of your result set. Try `$author_found_count = $search_author->num_rows;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is an array and should be accessed like that: review the documentation:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php